# Subquery returns more than 1 row SQL

Tags: sql

This query is returning more than one row:

```
SELECT T.Title FROM Titles T WHERE T.ArtistID = 
(SELECT A.ArtistID FROM Artists A WHERE A.Country = "USA");
```

Is it because it is ambigious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its because there is more than one artist in the USA.

What do you want?  All the titles written by authors in the USA?? Or all the titles for one specific Author?

If you want all the titles written by authors in the USA,

```
Select title from Titles
Where ArtistId In (Select ArtistID From artists
                   where Country = 'USA')
```

or

```
Select title from Titles t
    join Artists a 
        On a.ArtistId = t.ArtistId
Where a.Country = 'USA'
```

If you want the titles for one specific Author, you need to specify which specific author you want the titles for...

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have more then one artist with country = 'USA'

You can fix it like this to return just any title from any artist from USA

```
SELECT T.Title FROM Titles T WHERE T.ArtistID = 
(SELECT TOP 1 A.ArtistID FROM Artists A WHERE A.Country = "USA");
```

if you want all title with artists from USA use JOIN

```
SELECT T.Title FROM Titles T 
JOIN Artists A ON T.ArtistID = A.ArtistID
WHERE A.Country = "USA"
```

or

```
SELECT T.Title FROM Titles T WHERE T.ArtistID in
(SELECT TOP 1 A.ArtistID FROM Artists A WHERE A.Country = "USA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. Without seeing the data I can say why you have two rows.

How many ArtistIDs have a Country of USA?
Run the sub-query separately and see how many IDs it returns and which ones.

Then how many times do those ArtistIDs appear in the Titles table. My guess is more than one.